# A group representation restricted to a subgroup

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Consider a representation $\;A:\,G\longrightarrow GL(\mathbb{V})\;$ of a group $G$ in a vector space $\mathbb{V}\,$:
$$
A:\qquad G\times {\mathbb V} \longrightarrow {\mathbb V}\;,\quad (g,\,v)\longmapsto A_g\,v\;.
$$
For a subgroup $K<G$, we get its representation on $\mathbb V$ by forgetting how to act with elements outside $K$:
$$
A(G)\downarrow K:\qquad K\times {\mathbb V} \longrightarrow {\mathbb V}\;,\quad (k,\,v)\longmapsto A_k\,v\;.
$$
Now, a special case. Suppose $\mathbb V$ is the space of all functions $\varphi$ mapping the elements of $G$ to another vector space $\mathbb W\,$:
$$
{\mathbb{V}} = \left\{\varphi~\,{\Large{|}}\,~\varphi\,:~G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{W}}\right\}~,
$$
while $A$ is acting by left translations:
$$
\varphi(g^{\prime})\stackrel{g}{\longmapsto}\varphi(g^{-1}g^{\prime})\;,
$$
where $g^{\prime}$ is a free variable.

In this situation, what exactly is implied by restriction $A(G)\downarrow K\,$?

Evidently, we are now acting only by elements $k\in K$. Should we restrict the domain accordingly? This is to say, will the restriction be acting as
$$
\varphi(g^{\prime})\stackrel{k}{\longmapsto}\varphi(k^{-1}g^{\prime})\;,\quad k\in K
$$
or as
$$
\varphi(k^{\prime})\stackrel{k}{\longmapsto}\varphi(k^{-1}k^{\prime})\;,\quad k\in K\;,
$$
$g^{\prime}\in G\,$ and $\,k^{\prime}\in K\,$ being free variables.

We may consider each $\varphi(k')$ defined on $K<G$ as a function which is defined on $G$ but is set to be zero on elements outside $K$. So such functions constitute a subspace $\,^{^K}{\mathbb V}\subset\mathbb V$. This enables me to reformulate my question: does the restriction $A(G)\downarrow K$ imply a restriction of the domain from $\mathbb V$ to $\,^{^K}{\mathbb V}$ ?

Comment: You should specify that $G$ is assumed to be a topological group, or else drop the word "continuous" in your definition of $\mathbb{V}$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Sure. I may as well remove the redundant word "continuous", because it adds nothing to the story. (But yes, good point. Thank you.)

Comment: To answer your question: the definition you gave of $\downarrow K$ is precise and does *not* involve changing the vector space on which $G$ acts. So, the answer is "no".

Comment: Thank you, @diracdeltafunk . If you could shape your comment into a formal answer, that would enable me to give it due credit.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Would it be correct of me to say that the domain-restricted space of functions makes a subspace -- and therefore carries a subrepresentation of A(G)↓K ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn my comment into an answer:

No, by your own definition, $\downarrow K$ does not change the vector space on which the group acts.

It is true that $^K \mathbb{V}$ is a subrepresentation of $A \downarrow K$.